# Форма на Js

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте ,помогите сделать форму как здесь.
http://ritmyjizni.ru/Screenshot_1.png

При выборе шаблона из поле select ,содержание шаблона будет подставляться в textarea

Comment: Вы издеваетесь? Почему не потратить 15 минут на самостоятельные поиски? Это же элементарные действия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эх, не хочет народ отвечать на поставленный вопрос, как положено.

**html:**

```
<form>
    <div>Выберите шаблон из списка:</div>
    <select name="select" onchange="replaceText(this);">
        <option value="">- Выбрать / Без выбора -</option>
        <option value="Шаблон 1">Шаблон 1</option>
        <option value="Шаблон 2">Шаблон 2</option>
        <option value="Шаблон 3">Шаблон 3</option>
    </select>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="action" value="replace" checked />Заменить существующее сообщение
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="action" value="add" />Добавить в нижнюю часть</div>
    <textarea name="text"></textarea>
</form>
```

**javascript:**

```
function replaceText(object) {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName('action');
    var template = object.form.select.value;
    for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            if (radios[i].value === 'replace' && template !== '') {
                object.form.text.value = template;
            } else if (radios[i].value === 'add' && template !== '') {
                object.form.text.value +='\n'+template;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Демо: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/VK5f6/)**

Comment: А может народ слишком занят чтобы отвечать на **такие** вопросы как положено? К тому же если бы ТС чуточку мог шевелить мозгами, покопался бы в иходниках страницы с которой сдирал скрин и взял бы готовое решение!

Comment: Неделя от роду на Хэшкоде, еще альтруизм не выветрился :)
За старания вам конечно же thumbUp, но этим же вы поощряете лентяев

Comment: @Palmervan, я вас понимаю, но в этом случае, может быть, лучше пройти мимо?  
@dekameron, в первую очередь, решая (даже такие) задачи я сам учусь. Я плохо знаю javascript. Лучшее обучение - это практика.

Comment: Господа благодарю покорно вас. С формы я бы и сам содрал только доступа к ней у меня не было только скриншот. В js я не силен ,не моя область. Так что прошу извинить ,извольте откланяться )

Answer (score 1):

```
<form>
    <select name="select" onchange="this.form.text.value = this.form.select.value">
        <option value="">- Выбрать / Без выбора -</option>
        <option value="Шаблон 1">Шаблон 1</option>
        <option value="Шаблон 2">Шаблон 2</option>
        <option value="Шаблон 3">Шаблон 3</option>
    </select>
    <textarea name="text"></textarea>
</form>
```